# Unclickable space between label and checkbox if label has no background color

Tags: html, google-chrome, checkbox, label

I have checkbox inside label (so that user can click either on checbox or label). The problem is in Chrome there is small space between checkbox and label where clicks are not detected. I added yellow background color to see where the label ends and suddenly it worked. Does anyone knows why? Now I just added white background color in working code but I am really curious.

```html
<body>
  Between CheckBox1 and it's label is small unclickable space in chrome. In CheckBox2 there is not. The only difference is that label of CheckBox2 has set yellow background color. WTF?
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label style="background-color: yellow;"><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox2</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you should use `for` attribute of your label:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
<label for="my-checkbox">To check!</label>
```

Comment: He is talking about the **gap**

Comment: You can't click between checkbox and label either. Besides standard says: The label element represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute, or by putting the form control inside the label element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome renders checkboxes differently, that might be why. Not a traditional, right solution, but you could set `background:transparent` to solve the issue. Of course you could also fix this by adjusting `paddings, width` and so on.

```html
<body>
  Between CheckBox1 and it's label is small unclickable space in chrome. In CheckBox2 there is not. The only difference is that label of CheckBox2 has set yellow background color. WTF?
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label style="background-color: transparent;"><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox2</label>
  </div>
</body>
```